# PowerVM lpar specific cpu/mem info

Tags: virtual-machine, aix

I want to get the CPU and memory allocation information from lpars of PowerVM through HMC.

I have used

```
 lshwres -r proc -m <ms> --level lpar
 lssyscfg -r proc -m <ms>
```

The fields of interest are:

min_proc_units, desired_proc_units, max_proc_units, min_procs, desired_procs, max_procs

curr_min_proc_units, curr_proc_units, curr_max_proc_units, curr_min_procs, curr_procs, curr_max_procs, pend_min_proc_units, pend_proc_units, pend_max_proc_units, pend_min_procs, pend_procs, pend_max_procs

My question is how the `min_proc_units` and `curr_min_proc_units` correspond. Are these same information? Or the `curr_` says something else than what the 
profile of the lpar using `lssyscfg` says.

Answer (score 1):

The curr_* are the values for the running LPAR, then change when you use dynamic partition operations (DLPAR).

For example: lets say your LPAR profile defines desired_procs as 2, when your LPAR is activated the value for curr_desired_procs will be the same, 2. Now, lets say, you execute a DLPAR operation to change the desired procs to be 3. In that case your desired_procs value will still be 2, but your curr_desired_value will now be 3.

Another way to look at it is, the noncurr_* values are the ones defined in your partition profile, they are the ones used when you active a profie. The curr_* values are the ones of the running LPAR and they can be modified by DLPAR operations.

Comment: I get an error when i try to use  curr_procs or curr_procs with lssyscfg.

Comment: @randeepsp: Please start a new question for your issue, and provide essential details, like what particular command you used and what error you get.

Comment: @doktor5000 .did that . got the response @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254529/power-7-8-lpar-has-null-desired-proc-and-desired-mem/254695?noredirect=1
Thanks