# Power 7/8 - LPAR has null desired_proc and desired_mem

Tags: virtual-machine, aix, powerpc

I am querying the HMC via commands to get the memory and cpu of the logical partitions.
I am using the command lssyscfg.

For many lpars which are in Running or Not Activated status,
the command returns null for desired_procs and desired_mem.

But i am unable to create a lpar with null desired_procs=null and/or desired_mem=null .
How did the lpars get desired_mem and desired_procs as null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only places I see this are in profiles where `all_resources=1`, which makes sense for full-system LPARs. That's why the `lssyscfg` command return NULL values for those properties.

Comment: I do see all_resources=1 for the lpars where i am getting null as the output.
Can you point me to some documentation as to why this is done?
Also,how can i get the memory and cpu values from command line, as i can see assigned memory and cpu from the UI.

Comment: It is so hard to find documentation for HMC commands

Comment: A whole-system LPAR doesn't need min, max, or desired settings -- it uses the whole box. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER7/p7edm/p7edm_kickoff.htm?cp=8231-E1C&lang=en for an HMC command reference.

Comment: For memory and CPU information (at the system level), use `lshwres -r proc -m ... --level sys` and `lshwres -r mem -m ... --level sys`

Comment: Or for the other way around, to only query from inside the LPAR check `lparstat -i`

Comment: @doktor5000 i am looking for commands from hmc.

Comment: @JeffSchaller doktor5000 How do i create a whole-box partition ? Please point me to the doc if possible.

Comment: Tick the box that says as much when you create the lpa

Comment: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/8231-E1C/p7hat/iphblcreateprofilep6.htm